How to list all the data / records associated with a custom object type directly in salesforce?
Is there no way to see all the records for a custom object directly in salesforce?
For example if there is an object Foo__c, where do I list all the records showing the data populated for every instance of Foo__c in the system?
Thanks

If the object has less than 2000 rows, you can display all of them in a tabular report:

Create a Custom Report type for that particular object
Create a tabular report for that particular Report Type

If the object has more than 2000 rows, then the documentation states:

Reports display a maximum of 2,000 rows. To view more rows, export the report to Excel or use the printable view for tabular and summary reports.


I did (1). Is this saying I have to do (1) AND (2) or just (1) OR (2).
Also after creating the report it's not clear how to access it? Sorry, new to SF.

You need to do both unless the custom report type has been created when the object was created. Reports you'd access via App Launcher. There is a link called Reports. You can actually go through Trailhead to learn this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_implementation_reports_dashboards

after (1) I went to App Launcher and my report name was not listed.
Trying to follow (2), the very first step is "Select Add | Row Limit." I don't have any options on the setup/CustomReportTypes/page like that.
